# Gnuplot group by days

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to plot one bar per each day, where day value consists of sum of all values in the given day?
And if yes, is it possible to divide each "sum" bar into its sum components?

Let the **data** be

```
2017-09-25 13:56:51 10
2017-09-25 13:56:53 20
2017-09-25 19:20:53 30
2017-09-26 11:56:53 40
2017-09-26 13:17:02 20
2017-09-27 12:56:53 10
2017-09-28 09:56:54 30
2017-09-28 23:56:54 50
```

And the **desired output**

```
80                                           B
70                                           B
60       C           B                       B
50       C           B                       B
40       C           A                       B
30       B           A                       A
20       B           A                       A
10       A           A           A           A
 0   2017-09-25  2017-09-26  2017-09-27  2017-09-28
```

The colors do not have to be same across all columns, it is just for separating the sum components.

So far I have managed to plot just the bars, each per record:

```
set title "Durations sum per day"
unset multiplot
set xdata time
set style data boxes
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%m-%d\n%H:%M"
set xlabel "Day"
set ylabel "Duration sum"
set autoscale y
plot "my-data" using 1:3 t "duration [s]" with impulses linewidth 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply ignore the time for your plot and only use the date

```
plot dataf us (timecolumn(1,"%Y-%m-%d")):3 smooth freq with imp
```

and in the other case this should work

```
stats dataf us (timecolumn(1,"%Y-%m-%d"))
set style histogram columnstacked
plot for [i=STATS_min:STATS_max:60*60*24] dataf us (timecolumn(1,"%Y-%m-%d")==i?$3:NaN) w imp lw 10 title strftime("%Y-%m-%d",i)
```

but somehow "columnstacked" does not work with "plot for []"

Comment: I still wonder if I did sth wrong with the columnstacked option or if this is a bug....